# Django/HTML - what "value", "id" and "name" fields stand for?

Tags: html

I've gone through all the official Django tutorial, but I can't seem to figure out a template section of it.
I have the following form

```
<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' poll.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

I understand that this code accepts an input, and returns request.POST dictionary to the polls:vote view. However, in the 4th line of code, I don't understand what's the roll of name, id and value in this whole operation?

Could anyone give me a clue on this?

Comment: How much HTML do you know? This is not specific to Django or templating; those are just standard attributes of the `<input />` HTML element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is about HTML and not Python/Django.

- `id` is the unique identifier of the field in the page. It can be use in your CSS or Javascript after (and has no effects on the `request.POST` dict)
- `name` is an identifier, which will be used to fille the `request.POST` dict. Here, the only key that you'll have in your dict is `choice`
- `value` is the value of your radio button when you have select it. If you're submitting the form, `request.POST['choice']` will be equal to the value of the radio button selected

[More about the `input` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)